# Spark Structured Streaming is slow while reading messages with Custom Headers from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Im using Kafka and Spark 2.4 Structured Streaming with foreachBatch to read messages. Im getting Higher throughput (~3000 Messages/Sec) while consuming the events that are posted without Custom Headers, But while consuming the events that are with Custom Headers, the throughput is very low (~50 Messages/sec) and since includeHeaders option is also not available in Spark2.4, we are not including headers while consuming the message.

Comment: The headers are part of the record, regardless of the Spark options, and they are not deserialized, so I suspect there is something else going on (how large are your records?), and you should report a Spark JIRA so that someone can look at it

Comment: We process the records as JSON. Each JSON would 5-10kb approx. We have logged a cloudera ticket.